# Hello everyone, I have a problem with nfc

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tags, nfc

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unavailable, NFC is not available for device., null, null)

I use plugin NFC_MANAGER

Comment: Does the device actually have NFC hardware and is it turned on? You should catch this error and pop up a dialog box asking the user to turn on the NFC hardware.